# Asp.Net 5 TagHelper Modelstate binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

I'm trying to make a custom TagHelper that binds to the current ModelState, much like

```
<input asp-for="this_part" />
```

I would like to do some ModelState verification from my custom TagHelper-class.

Tried to search the [Github](https://github.com/aspnet/Razor) repository, but couldn't pinpoint this exact behavior. Anyone found a way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for, but the [DefaultHtmlGenerator does something similar for validation messages](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/caa8ea44fbc59d333dd82f571d756ce6876f0fae/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core/Rendering/Html/DefaultHtmlGenerator.cs#L564-584).

You can access the `ModelState` via the `ViewContext` (Sample adapted from [ValidationMessageTagHelper.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/64e726d2b26422c5452475627e4afaba307edec3/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers/ValidationMessageTagHelper.cs#L14-36)):

```
[TargetElement("span", Attributes = AttributeName)]
public class YourTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    private const string AttributeName = "your-for";

    [ViewContext]
    [HtmlAttributeNotBound]
    protected internal ViewContext ViewContext { get; set; }

    public override async Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        var modelState = ViewContext.ViewData.ModelState;
        // Your logic here
    }
}
```

From your comments, you mentioned that you wanted intellisense for mapping to a Model property. [ValidationMessageTagHelper.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/64e726d2b26422c5452475627e4afaba307edec3/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers/ValidationMessageTagHelper.cs#L14-36) does this with this property:

```
[HtmlAttributeName(ValidationForAttributeName)]
public ModelExpression For { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thank you. That is almost what I want, as it helps with modelstate-validation.

However; this doesn't bring the Model intellisense, when typing in the "for"-attribute of the html element.  

I get the value of the "for"-attribute, by adding this code:
[HtmlAttributeName("for")] public string AttributeFor { get; set; }

, but no intellisense. Maybe it should be different type than "string" ?

Comment: Updated my answer for you to answer your follow-up question. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: According to https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/28, [Activate] is going away in beta-5.

Comment: From beta-5 onward, you can use `[HtmlAttributeNotBound] [ViewContext]` in place of `[Activate]`